# WPF binding validation incorect prefix

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm new in WPF and I'm trying to implement binding validation from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396,

I copy the XAML and c# code from the site and there is problem with the prefix in XAML

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" FontSize="15"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
         Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Age" Source="{StaticResource ods}"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <c:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

It is written that there is no c prefix. I tried to use all of possible prefixes but it throw that AgeValidationRule is not supported in this prefix.

How can i make this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is written that there is no c prefix.

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <c:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

`XAML` uses a `prefix` to map a `namespace` in your solution. Meaning somewhere in the msdn's sample code within the xaml should have declared the `c` prefix that maps to the namespace where `AgeRangeRule` class should be located.

For simplicity you could just add the `AgeRangeRule` class to your project and use the `local` prefix which maps to your project's namespace (e.g. `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"` means that I have named my project `WpfApplication1` so whatever class I put within that `namespace` can be accessed through the prefix `local`.

> AgeValidationRule is not supported in this prefix.

This shows that you have changed the sample xaml code like this...

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <c:AgeValidationRule  Min="21" Max="130"/>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

so with that you should also change the sample `AgeRangeRule` class provided by msdn to `AgeValidationRule`... and place that into the `namespace` in which the `prefix` `c` maps to. (OR just put it in your project's namespace and use the prefix `local` as I've mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

To make it working make sure you follow the following steps :

1. Go to Visual Studio
2. Select Create New Project -> WPF Project
3. Copy the above code into your `<Grid> </Grid>` tag
4. Create a class named **AgeRangeRule.cs** in your project and add below code to the class file.

   public class AgeRangeRule : ValidationRule
   {
       private int _min;
       private int _max;

   ```
   public AgeRangeRule()
   {
   }

   public int Min
   {
       get { return _min; }
       set { _min = value; }
   }

   public int Max
   {
       get { return _max; }
       set { _max = value; }
   }

   public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   {
       int age = 0;

       try
       {
           if (((string)value).Length > 0)
               age = Int32.Parse((String)value);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters or " + e.Message);
       }

       if ((age < Min) || (age > Max))
       {
           return new ValidationResult(false,
             "Please enter an age in the range: " + Min + " - " + Max + ".");
       }
       else
       {
           return new ValidationResult(true, null);
       }
   }
   ```

   }
5. Now add the namespace to your project such as below

   xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"

where c is the referred namespace here and WpfApplication2 is to be replaced by your solution name.

**EDIT :**  Updated XAML Code below.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" FontSize="15"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
         Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Age" Source="{StaticResource ods}"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: okey, i got it but now, i hava another problem `Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}`" throws that it cant be resolved, same for `Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"` and `Source="{StaticResource ods}"`

Comment: You need to add up the code in msdn. I have edited the question. Please check. For **ods** you need to add a static resource also. That depends upon your requirement.

Comment: Also try to learn WPF basics, by referring some tutorials. Without that it will be very difficult for you.